# Add minimize button to JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I was wondering how you would make a jbutton, on click, minimize a jpanel.  I'm pretty much building my own title bar, so I need this to be custom and not the built in one.  Thanks.

To be clear, I need it to do what the "-" button does on the title bar of a window.

Comment: Do you *"minimize a window"*?

Comment: Ya the window which is a jframe/jpanel.

Comment: You already have an answer, which surprises me, but you really should try to solve this yourself and if that fails ask us by demonstrating what you've attempted, what results you received and what you expected.

Comment: @izuriel Why even respond then?  Your response contains no useful information at all.  What results I received and expected?  I needed one method call to minimize a jframe.  I don't really understand why I would post random unrelated code when all I need is one method call.  I hate people like you.  Just useless and unhelpful.

Comment: @Robert It's actually in the StackOverflow [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "_Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results._" and whether you hate people like me or not is your choice, I'm sorry you get so irate.

Comment: You can not follow the FAQ but you can't expect to do that and not get some negative response. Try Googling "java minimize jframe" and you will find out why you did not really need to ask the question. Incidentally using Google could have saved you 8 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To minimize a frame:

```
frame.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
```

To normalize

```
frame.setState(JFrame.NORMAL);
```